# Gitlab upgrade but gitlab.rb unchange

Tags: gitlab

I am using GitLab CE. I upgrade GitLab CE from 7.14.3 to 8.9.6 through apt-get upgrade. After successfully upgrade, I found that the gitlab configuration file which locates in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb keeps the same.

But why? I thought that GitLab upgrade would automatically update the new features to gitlab.rb. For now, I have to copy the newest configuration file and find the difference and then merge it to my current gitlab.rb.

Is there any way to auto upgrade configuration file to the newest and merge the configuration which I had changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check the diff with `gitlab-ctl diff-config`.

Then change what's new so the diff is minimal or if you have no changed done to `gitlab.rb` you can just copy `/opt/gitlab/etc/gitlab.rb.template` over it.